# Ruby on Rails/PostGRE - No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am obtaining this error on my Ruby on Rails app,

```
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I've read on the stack overflow API and can't find an answer that works for me. So this is the specific parts of the code:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Store#show_item

Showing /media/store_test/app/views/store/show_item.html.erb where line #24 raised:

PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...CT "show_item".* FROM "current_item" WHERE (user_id = 1)
                                                               ^
```

My logic behind this error is that I have two users, store users and employee users, they are both users but employee users have a "flag" on them, so they can see all items in store. Store users do not have this flag, so this web page should show items they have "wishlisted", and when I create a table to populate this, I am getting the above error/

This code works when Im a employee user, and populates my table as required, but does not work when I'm a store user.

**Question**: How can I fix this error without heavily modifying my code?

EDIT: SCHEMA

```
  create_table "current_item", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",                default: "", null: false
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "cost"
    t.datetime "created_at",                       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                       null: false
    t.string   "user_id"
  end
```

Comment: Can you paste your table definition from `schema.rb` for `current_item` table?

Comment: I've edited the description just now

Comment: Are you using standard, integer ids? Your `user_id` is a string and PostgreSQL is failing on comparing strings to integers. You've probably defined your `user_id` column with a wrong type, should be integer (unless you're using uuids, which is less probable).

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks for that. So I've edited it to t.integer and then did rake db:migrate, but I still get the error obtained. Is there something I've done wrong, as I feel your explanation is hitting the dot.

Comment: Is it exactly the same error you're getting? If so, can you check in your `schema.rb` whether you're seeing `t.integer "user_id"` for `current_item` table?

Comment: You need to redo that migration, just editing the migration and doing a `db:migrate` won't do anything. Also, you might want to use `t.references :user` instead of `t.integer :user_id`.

Comment: Hi Marcin and mu. So it was supposed to be t.integer, and I've now just updated the scheme using migration, not editing the schema manually (my stupidity!). Everything is working correctly now, so thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marcin Kologziej:

user_id column was defined with the wrong type. Instead of strings, it should have been integer, as per the error. Therefore, I have created a new migration, using the code:

```
change_column :current_item, :user_id, :integer, using: 'user_id_id::integer'
```

And then performing:

```
rake db:migrate
```

And everything works perfectly now.